# Android Sqlite multiple tables in one DB

Tags: java, android, sqlite

A quick question guys,

Currently I have one table in my Database, I need a total of 6. Is it simply a case of declaring my column name variables for the other 5 tables then adding 5 create statements in the onCreate method? This will obviously mean i can keep all my database handling in one class.

I've done some research into it but just want to make sure Im going in the right direction.

Comment: Yep, that's more or less it.

Comment: @mango Thanks, just trying to save some trouble later on!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer is yes - you can create as many tables inside one SQLite database as you need.